# Decryption error on image data in Andorid

Tags: android, image, kotlin, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt images using the below code.

The problem is whenever the size of the images goes above 400KB (approximately, depends on the device), I get an `AEADBadTagException` on decryption.

**Encryption**:

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
val iv = ByteArray(12)
val random = SecureRandom()
random.nextBytes(iv)

val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(), spec)

val ivCTAndTag = ByteArray(12 + cipher.getOutputSize(valueToEncrypt.size))
System.arraycopy(iv, 0, ivCTAndTag, 0, 12)

val valueToDecrypt = cipher.doFinal(valueToEncrypt, 0, valueToEncrypt.size, ivCTAndTag, 12)
```

**Decryption**:

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, valueToDecrypt, 0, 12)
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(), spec)

cipher.doFinal(valueToDecrypt, 12, valueToDecrypt.size - 12)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Added.

Comment: Still not. Do you remember/know [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean)?

Comment: when decrypting, where does "valueToDecrypt" come from? it seems this should be the same as "ivAndCTWithTag"

Comment: Yes that's right.
I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Android keystore is not thread-safe. When you use Android keystore to encrypt and decrypt big chunk of data, you need to mark the method as `synchronized`.

Actually all the methods related to Android keystore, you need to make sure them thread-safe.

Comment: For more details, please refer to https://medium.com/@weidianhuang/how-to-write-thread-safe-code-for-android-keystore-40a0fa17f416